# ggplot facet_grid panel.spacing w/ axis label position = "right"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating a heatmap/tile plot with faceting on both the `x` and `y` axes, and for some reason the spacing of the panel labels is not correctly matching the spacing of the data panels.

Here is example data and a plot.

```
library(data.table)
td = data.table(Sym=rep(paste0("sym",1:14),141),
                sample=rep(paste0("sample",1:141), 14),
                value = sample(x=0:100, size=141*14,replace=T)/100,
                group = rep(c(rep(1,12),rep(2,34),rep(3,28),rep(4,27),rep(5,40)),14)
           )
td[, category := ifelse(Sym %in% paste0("sym",1:5), "cat1",
                        ifelse(Sym %in% paste0("sym",6:10), "cat2",
                               ifelse(Sym %in% paste0("sym",11:14), "cat3",NA)))]

p = ggplot(td, 
       aes(x=sample,y=Sym, fill=value))+
  geom_tile()+
  facet_grid(category ~ group,scales = "free",space = "free", switch = "y")+
  scale_y_discrete(position = "right")+
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        strip.text.y = element_text(angle=180),
        strip.text.x = element_text(color="white"))
p
```

[image: unequal facets]

Notice how the y axis facets are not perfectly aligned with the tileplot of the data.  I tried to change the panel spacing in the theme, and the issue still persists:

```
p+theme(panel.spacing = unit(0,"lines"))
```

[image: after changing panel spacing]

Finally, I can fix it by resetting the y axis scale:

```
p+scale_y_discrete(position="right", expand = c(0,0))
```

[image]

It looks like this is caused by me setting the y axis labels to plot on the right side of the plot using `scale_y_discrete(position="right")`.  Is there a better way to set the y-axis labels to plot on the right side without it affecting the facet spacing?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the position. If you run the code with `scale_y_discrete()` (i.e. default position, default expansion), you'll observe the same phenomenon. By default, discrete scales have an additive constant of 0.6 on either end. Setting `expand = c(0, 0)` as you have done is an appropriate to remove it.

Comment: if that is the case, then doesn't it seem a bit weird that the default behavior leads to unaligned facet labels and facet panels?